Uploading multiple local parquet files to bq
I have ~100 local parquet files that must be loaded to bigquery as a single table.  All files are in a single directory and have identical schema.  I have tried the following

Combine locally then upload to bq

#in python
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

input_dir = '/dir/with/parquet/files'
dataset = ds.dataset(input_dir, format="parquet")
pq.write_table(dataset.to_table(), "big_file.pqt")

The issue here is that the files are around 300gigs total and we run out of memory.  If this can be done in chunks maybe, but I don't know if this is possible

load all directory as single file using command line tool

#in command line
bq load --source_format=PARQUET my-project:mydataset.biqfile \
 "/dir/with/parquet/files/*.pqt"

This throws exceptions.  I have tried several different flavors of the above, such as a) removing the quotes from the last line and b) changing the last line to
/dir/with/parquet/files/\*.pqt.  All have thrown exceptions.  I am a total beginner at scripting so maybe there is something obvious missing here.

I wrote a script that loads each file sequentially into the desired table.  Here is the code:
import os
import subprocess
import argparse
import sys

project = 'my-project' 
dataset = 'my_dataset'
table =   'my-table'

#create an empty table
create_table_cmd = f'bq mk --table {project}:{dataset}.{table}'
print(f"Creating table: {create_table_cmd}")
subprocess.run(create_table_cmd, shell=True, check=True)

# Load data into the table
for file in os.listdir(parquet_dir):
    if file.endswith(('.parquet', '.pqt')):
        file_path = os.path.join(parquet_dir, file)
        load_cmd = f'bq load --source_format=PARQUET --autodetect {dataset}.{table} "{file_path}"'
            print(f"Loading file: {load_cmd}")
            subprocess.run(load_cmd, shell=True, check=True)


